# Update column values sequentially where the new value is based on updated values in a 'previous' row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

Consider the following table:

```
select id, val, newval from test1;
 id | val | newval
----+-----+--------
  1 |   1 |      0
  2 |   2 |      0
  3 |   5 |      0
  4 |   9 |      0
  5 |  10 |      0
```

I am looking for an update query that can sequentially update the values in the *newval* column where the updated value is the difference between *val* and *val.prev* (the value of *val* in the previous row) plus the UDATED value of *newval* from the previous row. The result would be:

```
select id, val, newval from test1;
 id | val | newval
----+-----+--------
  1 |   1 |      0 = set to zero since result would be NULL (no previous row exists)
  2 |   2 |      1 = 2  - 1 + 0
  3 |   5 |      4 = 5  - 2 + 1
  4 |   9 |      8 = 9  - 5 + 4
  5 |  10 |      9 = 10 - 9 + 8
                              ^ - uses updated value of newval
```

I came close to a solution with the following:

```
WITH tt AS (
    SELECT id, COALESCE(val - lag(val) OVER w + lag(newval) OVER w,0) as nv 
    FROM test1
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY id)
    )
UPDATE test1 SET newval = tt.nv FROM tt
WHERE test1.id = tt.id;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
select id, val, newval from test1;
 id | val | newval
----+-----+--------
  1 |   1 |      0
  2 |   2 |      1 = 2  - 1 + 0
  3 |   5 |      3 = 5  - 2 + 0
  4 |   9 |      4 = 9  - 5 + 0
  5 |  10 |      1 = 10 - 9 + 0
                              ^ - uses old value of newval
```

but this solution does not use the updated values of *newval*. It uses the old values.

I know I can write a function to loop through the table one row at a time but from what I have read this method would be inefficient and normally discouraged. My actual application is more complicated and involves large tables so efficiency is important.

Comment: In Oracle there is a lag group function.  See if there is an equivalent of that in your db

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that your logic reduces to:

```
select id, val, (val - 1) as newval
from t;
```

Why?  You are taking a cumulative sum of the difference between `val` and `val` in the previous row.  The cumulative difference ends up being the most recent value minus the first value.

The first value is `1`.  The above hardcodes that value.  It would be easy enough to adjust the logic for the first value:

```
select id, val,
       (val - first_value(val) over (order by id) as newval
from t;
```

Comment: This is a trivial example. I am not looking for a solution only for this exact problem. Ultimately I am looking for a solution to update column values sequentially (ie. when the next column value depends on the updated value from the previous row). The sample table and calculations are provided to help explain my question. Do not focus on the math being performed.

Comment: @iamthebull . . . This answers the question that you asked.  The fact that it reduces to a trivial example is because that is what you asked.  If you have a different question, then I would recommend that you ask a new question.  As an aside, I think you should accept this, because it is by far the simplest and most performant solution to your question.

Comment: I repeat... my question is about updating rows in a table sequentially where new row values depend on updated values from the previous row (see question title). Do you have any input on that?